Реализация удаленной БД для десктопного приложения
Есть простое десктоп-приложение, которое написано на Python, в него вносят данные и по итогу получают Word-файл, готовый для печати, и все внесенные данные вносятся в БД. Задача — загрузить образно файл с БД на хостинг, чтобы приложение на любом из ПК сотрудников имело доступ к актуальной БД. Подскажите как это реализовать или в какую сторону копать

Sqlite сейчас там?

Так сотрудники все внутри какой-то одной локальной сети или в разных сетях и общаются через интернет между собой? Ну и да - что за БД конкретно? Добавьте тег с названием БД.

Sqlite там, да. Программа лежит на локальном сервере и сотрудники заходят в серверную папку и открывают программу. Но есть и сотрудники на удаленке и им приходится подключаться извне.

Тут нужно всю схему видеть. И обычно всё-таки никто прямо БД наружу не выставляет. Выставляют какой-то интерфейс API, через который идёт работа с БД. С авторизацией, логированием и т.д. Вообще это всё выглядит так, что у вас есть простенькая программа, рассчитанная только на локальную работу, а вы пытаетесь из неё сделать более серьёзное многопользовательское решение с удалённым доступом. Так обычно не делается, по-нормальному программу нужно переписывать, менять архитектуру решения. Сейчас вы понаделаете костылей, и может даже это будет работать, но вряд ли будет долго и хорошо.

Просто как я понял у меня два варианта, 1) Оставлять десктоп приложение, реализовав удаленную бд и так же обновления программы в автоматическом/полуавтоматическом режиме 2) Оставлять логику и запихивать ее в веб на Django (что в общем то решит все проблемы)

Если можно перетащить на нормальную систему типа Django, то было бы хорошо. Там и авторизация и всё прочее и допиливать что-то будет не сложно.
